# Optimize writes to heroku Postgresql database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, heroku, talend

We are dealing with quite a lot of incoming events that we process with Talend and afterwards push them in different postgresql databases (local and remote heroku db). Because of the the session option setAutoCommit(true) we are facing big performance penalties especially on the heroku database (each statement/insert is a new transaction that has to be commited).

Unfortunately because of a talend bug we cannot commit in batches that would improve the performance. Because of the generated overhead I was thinking to change the session to make asyncrhonous commit however on the java.sql.Connection documentation I could not find any useful information how to do it. From talend to postgresql we are using a single persistent connection.

My questions are:

- Can be asynchronous commits configured through java connection/driver (postgresql 9.3)? We want to configure it on the session basis and not for the whole database.
- What other option do I have to reduce the transaction overhead? Like I said every insert is now in each own transaction.
- Any other option?

Links:

- [postgresql asynchronous commit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/wal-async-commit.html)
- java doc: [java.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)
- issue on [talend forum](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=37184)

Comment: What's the Talend bug stopping you from batch inserting? I can't find an open JIRA on it.

Comment: Jira ticket was opened today by talend support but I do not know if is public or not (https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-30083).  Ticket describes the problem when using rest web services with tpostgresqloutput component. Both options  "use an existing connection" and "use batch size" on the component does not work if used in combination with rest web services. For the first option we have found a workaroud but for the second we are still looking for a solution.

Comment: I can't see the ticket right now apparently. I assume you're making the connection directly in the component rather than using the tPostrgreSQLConnection component to avoid the first problem? That precludes the chance of you using a tPostgreSQLCommit component unfortunately. I'm not sure how the error is manifesting but one option might be to hash what data would normally be sent to Postgres and then separately read that hash back in in another subjob and use a tPostgreSQLConnection with a tPostgreSQLCommit after your tPostgreSQLOutput component.

Comment: The problem with tPostrgreSQLConnection and "Use existing connection" was that a local variable of postgresqlOutput was populated from globalMap with a null value. I bypassed this issue by saving the connection object in a context variable that was afterwards used to update the globalMap just before the execution of the statement (this was achieved by fFlexJava).  I tried to implement batch logic in the same tflex component but it was unreliable - some events were saved and some not.

Comment: Here is a pic representing a part of the job 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bya3za07dsit2c8/000013.png

Comment: Is it whether the RESTful web service components are used in the job at all or whether it's in the flow of data? If performance is a massive drag then you've got a couple of potential options: If you can use both RESTful and Postgres components in the same job but not same subjob then maybe hash the result from the web service (post JSON handling) and then read the hash back in to a subjob with a proper tPostgreSQLConnection and tPostgreSQLCommit series of sub jobs.

Comment: If you can't even do that and performance is really critical then you could use a job to land the data into a  temporary flat file or alternative database before then using another job to extract the data from there to the intended Postgres target. You'd need another job to clean up your temporary tables/flat files as well. It's hideous but it would be a better work around if it's really just a RESTful and Postgres combination problem.

Comment: I tried to divide jobs but did not help probably because all the processing resides in the same loop? Despite tBuffering the output of the tMap I was thinking to use some MOM concepts and JMS queues however this is another complexity to handle (queues, queues server, etc..). I tried to read from tBufferInput and batches works fine  but I cannot make it play well within a parent job. In the current implementation are problematic remote writes that blocks the ingestion of all future events so first I will save them to the local machine and afterwards I will move them in batches with another job.

Comment: Any other hint? I realy appreciate your help  ydaetskcoR.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've not used PostgreSQL with Talend but typically inserts are done in batches and it's only the default behaviour of Talend that auto commits them - I assume this is the session option that you're seeing here.

You could try setting your job up to use a tPostgreSQLConnection and then finish it with a tPostgreSQLCommit OnSubjobOk to do the commit all at once. Performance from single insert batches may be poor anyway but it should improve things.

Comment: Some addition to this: you could do a tJava with a counter++ parallel to the inserts then with an If link you can execute a commit when your counter reaches 100 or so. counter += (counter >1000 ? -1000 : 1)

Comment: That's not a bad idea but I'd probably throw the counter into a Numeric.Sequence in the flow of data just to make the counter simpler. I'm also, generally, a fan of making job wide commits (only commit everything at the end) unless I specifically need otherwise because it makes error recovery far simpler if you don't have to worry about what you might have committed before the job failed.

Comment: Normally I would aggree with you but keep in mind that this webservice that will run 7/24 so even my idea isn't the best one., If there's only 90 insert then for a few hours there aren't new insert you still want to commit. Probably a bruteforce commit every 5-10-15minute could overcome on this.